# Finding surface tension of water at certain temperature and pressure

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, water, surface-tension

The question is:

> Using the Young-Laplace Equation (if applicable), find the surface tension (dynes/cm) for water at 20 
>               degrees Celsius with 2.5 psi. Round to the nearest tenth.

Well, I didn't use the Young-Laplace equation, not sure if needed though. What I did was use the [Eötvös rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E%C3%B6tv%C3%B6s_rule) and its special case for water to solve the question. The equation is:

$$\gamma = 0.07275\;\frac{N}{m}\;\times\;(1-0.002\times(T-291K))$$

What I did was convert 20 Celsius to Kelvin (293K) and then put it in the equation to get:

$$\gamma = 0.07275\;\frac{N}{m}\;\times\;(1-0.002\times(293K-291K))= 0.072459\frac{N}{m}$$

However, I think I may be wrong as this does not account for pressure at all. Which ends up becoming about $72.46\frac{dynes}{cm}$ Am I right or wrong? And is there a better/correct way of doing this?

Comment: Why the downvote? This question definitely "shows research effort"...

Comment: Is it safe to assume we're dealing with a water droplet? I'd like to model the problem as a spherical bead of water in air whose radius is a function of temperature (and pressure). Also, I'm fairly certain whether or not the Young-Laplace equation is applicable hinges on this point.

Comment: @DavidH, I honestly don't know, this is all the context I'm given, so I can't be certain, but I'm guessing you could.

Comment: @Link On an unrelated note, whoever wrote this question is either evil or an idiot just for using pounds-per-square-inch pressure units but dynes and centimeters for force and distance units.

Comment: @DavidH, agreed :p I actually had to search up dynes to see... And that would be my professor

Comment: Without a diagram it is impossible to know what is the meaning of this pressure - is it the partial vapor pressure of water above the surface? I would downvote your professor for an extremely poorly phrased problem..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Using the Young-Laplace Equation (if applicable)

Basically a trick question trying to get you to equate the pressure in the question with $\Delta P$ in the Young-Laplace equation.

The actually pressure dependence of water's surface tension is given in [On the Evaluation of the Surface Tension-Pressure Coefficient for Pure Liquids](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021979785710296#)

The rate of change of surface tension with respect to pressure is $7 \times 10^{-8} cm$ near atmospheric pressure.  So since the question says "Round to the nearest tenth", the pressure effect is insignificant.